# Receiving this error "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(OpportunityTeamMember) from the type List<List<OpportunityTeamMember>>"

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, list, variable

I am trying to pass a list of records back into a flow as a collection variable but keep hitting this error ***Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(OpportunityTeamMember) from the type List<List>***  This is my code:

```
//invocable method to create OpportunityTeamMember records from a list of Opportunity Ids
@InvocableMethod(label='Create OTM Records for OOO' description='Given a list of Opportunity IDs, create OTM records from these IDs.')
    public static List<List<OpportunityTeamMember>> createOTMRecords(List<InputVariables> inputVariables) {

        //inputs
        List<Opportunity> opps = inputVariables.get(0).Opportunities;
        String UserId;
        
        //outputs
        List<List<OpportunityTeamMember>> otmOutputs = new List<List<OpportunityTeamMember>>();
        for(Opportunity o : opps){
            OpportunityTeamMember otm = new OpportunityTeamMember();
            otm.OpportunityId = o.Id;
            otm.UserId = UserId;
            otm.TeamMemberRole = 'Mortgage Banker';
            otm.OpportunityAccessLevel = 'Edit';
            otmOutputs.add(otm);
        }
        system.debug('otmOutputs >>>>' + otmOutputs);
        return otmOutputs;
    }    

    public class InputVariables {
        @InvocableVariable
        public List <Opportunity> Opportunities;

        @InvocableVariable
        public String UserId;
    }
```

Comment: `otmOutputs.add(otm)` - you need to add a list of otms, not a singleton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, you need to add a List of Opportunity Team Member records to your output, not just a single Opportunity Team Member.

Assuming you're expecting to return a single list (which is how I read your supplied code), you should be able to do the following:

```
    public static List<List<OpportunityTeamMember>> createOTMRecords(List<InputVariables> inputVariables) {

        //inputs
        List<Opportunity> opps = inputVariables.get(0).Opportunities;
        String UserId;
        
        //outputs
        List<List<OpportunityTeamMember>> otmOutputs = new List<List<OpportunityTeamMember>>();

        List<OpportunityTeamMember> otmList = new List<OpportunityTeamMember>();

        for(Opportunity o : opps){
            OpportunityTeamMember otm = new OpportunityTeamMember();
            otm.OpportunityId = o.Id;
            otm.UserId = UserId;
            otm.TeamMemberRole = 'Mortgage Banker';
            otm.OpportunityAccessLevel = 'Edit';
            otmList.add(otm);
        }
        otmOutputs.add(otmList);
        system.debug('otmOutputs >>>>' + otmOutputs);
        return otmOutputs;
    }    

    public class InputVariables {
        @InvocableVariable
        public List <Opportunity> Opportunities;

        @InvocableVariable
        public String UserId;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much @CallumMacErlich.  Looks like I was just missing the inner list assignment.  This helped me a lot.